# unwanted nvm manual printout during shell initialization

Tags: zsh

I have installed nvm using homebrew, and I have the default .zshrc file:

```
export NVM_DIR="$HOME/.nvm"
[ -s "$HOMEBREW_PREFIX/opt/nvm/nvm.sh" ] && \. "$HOMEBREW_PREFIX/opt/nvm/nvm.sh" # This loads nvm
[ -s "$HOMEBREW_PREFIX/opt/nvm/etc/bash_completion.d/nvm" ] && \. "$HOMEBREW_PREFIX/opt/nvm/etc/bash_completion.d/nvm" # This loads
nvm bash_completion
```

Whenever I open a terminal, the whole nvm manual page gets printed, which is esp. annoying when I open new tabs in the WebStorm's embedded terminal. How do I remove that initial printout without causing any harm to the initialization process?